# What would be the milestone based on ratings that would give expert validation in StackOverflow? Are there such specific process?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Let's say user A has received different milestones. Does StackOverflow have any ways of identifying that this user A now belongs to an expert community for this specific subject?

Comment: Hi, I think it doesn't have that answer. It's not about no. of badges, but what no. of badges when you get declare you that you are expert? Is there some system in SO? That was my question, could you please read first before down-voting??

Comment: Tag badges is the sum total of what Stack Overflow has towards identifying anyone as an expert.

Comment: expert in field == at least 5% of Jon Skeet's rep. =)

Comment: But, my question is.. can you declare that you have "x" amount of tag-badges and then you are "expert"? Does SO have that system provided? That was my question

Comment: Martijin Pieters.. can I down-vote your comment? Seems you don't read questions properly. :)

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a profession certification authority. o.o

Comment: Why would we have a system like that? How would such a thing even be determined? Should we just pick some arbitrary number?

Comment: That's why this is under "discussion" tag.

Comment: Also related: [Writing C++ expert on my CV](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66004) and [Recognizing leading contributors and experts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128625)

Comment: Alright, makes sense. Thanks Cody Gray.

Answer (score 6):

No, there's nothing that officially identifies a user as an expert in a subject on Stack Overflow.  The closest thing we have is the tag badges: [Bronze](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze), [Silver](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=silver), and [Gold](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold).  These merely indicate that a user has gotten X upvotes on Y posts in that tag (see the links for actual values of X and Y for each badge).

Answer (score 1):

They'd have Bronze, Silver and Gold tag badges for the topics they were answering in, depending on the votes they'd received in those tags.

See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) about half way down.